# Add a transparent gradient to a JPanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, transparency, jpanel

I'm drawing a couple of shapes on a JPanel using the `paintComponent()` method. The final touch is to add a transparent white gradient towards the top.

I have this:

[image: 1]

and I want to get something like this:

[image: 2]

I've tried to use the GradientPaint method, but it doesn't seem to work properly for me at all. When I call `g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(...))`, it can't seem to draw over the existing pixels at all.

If anyone would like to see what I'm doing, an SSCCE of the code is available at [**this Pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/hqA3ZYRr).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also look into alt+printscreen to crop screenshots.  A tip from [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: I've posted an SSCCE. Thanks! I use Windows 7's snipping tool, as I need to capture from a windowed Virtual Machine

Comment: unrelated: never-ever change the state of the component in paintComponent! (simply remove the setPrefSize, you shouldn't use that particular method _anywhere_)

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks. I was using it early on for layout testing (with other components), and forgot to remove it. Since the width is preferred to be around 150, I forgot it there and mistakenly assumed it was being laid out in the frame just fine.

Comment: @kleopatra do you have any references or anything that recommends *against* using `setPref.Size()`?

Comment: not only not setPref, but also the other two :-) For a discusion on why not see f.i http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to produce an effect if these are added as the last lines of `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

```
// now we have set a paint, DO SOMETHING WITH IT!
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try applying a `AlphaComposite` before painting the gradient

```
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
```

The other thing you could try is to use a color with an alpha value within the gradient...

```
LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
    startPoint, endPoint, new float[]{...}, 
    new Color[] {
        new Color(255, 255, 255, 0),
        new Color(255, 255, 255, 128),
        new Color(255, 255, 255, 0),
    });
```

Comment: What values should I use for the `float` array? 0.5 and 1.0 are OK?

Comment: That's up to you 0.0 is fully transparent, 1f is fully opaque. Personally, I'd try anywhere between 0.25f - 0.75f & see what you like

Comment: I ended up using this in a different way, but it pointed me in the right direction. The composite command seems to apply a mask over the entire component, which isn't what I was looking for//

Comment: @Redandwhite Yep, that it will do, so you need to paint the "solid" areas first, then the "alpha" parts later ;)

Comment: Ah okay! I ended up using the LGP above (with custom values), set it using `g.setPaint(lgp)`, and then used this answer on the very last line of `paintComponent()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12139321/216104

Comment: @Redandwhite Yeah, that's probably the easier.  `AlphaComposite` is really good for painting shapes and images ;)